# spacemacs: multiple cursors (evil-mode)

Tags: spacemacs

Is it possible to configure multiple cursors in `spacemacs` in `evil-mode`? If so, how?

To be clear, I'm interested in a way to insert text at multiple points simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Would [evil-iedit-state](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#replacing-text-with-iedit) work for you? Iedit state allows you to edit/insert/delete multiple occurrences of a particular word or pattern. It works within an entire file or just within a particular region. It doesn't work to edit multiple arbitrary points with nothing in common though.

Answer (score 1):

Is [evil-mc](https://github.com/gabesoft/evil-mc) suit for you?

evil-mc provides multiple cursors functionality for Emacs when used with evil-mode.